# Using Fail2Ban as non root

Tags: user-management, fail2ban, root

What is the best way to add IP to Fail2Bans blocklist for normal user, (non root) but without giving full acces to fail2ban-client for that normal user.

To run for example this command for normal user:

```
fail2ban-client set apache-badbots addignoreip 193.81.151.209
```

Comment: Hmm, tough one. I'm not a linux expert but perhaps you could grant the user access to a folder. Then create a script they can run passing the ip address to ban. The script creates a file via touch command in that folder. For example touch /etc/ban-folder/1.2.3.4 and you can create a cron job to read filenames as root and block ip addresses. It sounds complicated when I say it out loud, but it's a work around I guess.

Comment: I was asking for 'the best way'.
Not any strange ideas that I would have myself.

Comment: I will be interested in any answers you get. My understanding is that root and sudoers are the only ones able to execute anything where root access is required. I hope you get a good answer because I'll learn something.

Answer (score 1):

we used this scenario some time ago, it worked for us.

**Credit goes to [Jinn Koriech](https://coderwall.com/jinnko)**

His article contains many good points and hints:
https://coderwall.com/p/haj28a/running-rootless-fail2ban-on-debian

> Where possible we prefer to run services as a non-root user. fail2ban
>   also supports this, however the run-rootless.txt docs don't fully
>   detail all the necessary steps.
>
> Some of the steps are explained in the /etc/default/fail2ban config
>   script. In addition to these a few other steps are needed. Below are
>   all the steps to get a working rootless fail2ban on debian wheezy.

Comment: Very interesting and new info to me. I'm going to give it a try. I use firewalld rather than iptables and will be interested in the results. I think I'll create a VM for this rather than screwing around with my production servers. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, im not able to run Fail2ban as non root user.